# Analytically show that the graph of the function $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+6x$ has no horizontal tangent lines.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I ended up taking the derivative and found my value of $x$ to be $$x=\frac{-10}{3}$$ but after this I am not sure how to proceed help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you did and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$f'(x) = 3(x+\frac23)^2+ \frac{14}3> 0$